# Wordpress ID was called incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

So i've been trying to fix this error and couldnt find a solution anywhere. I have a front page that loads just fine when im not logged in as a admin, but when i log in as a admin it throws me this error and some elementor blocks are not showing up. This is the error i get. My wordpress version is 5.9.2, Woocomerce version - 6.3.1, Elementor 3.6.1.

ID was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/puca/page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, Elementor\Frontend->apply_builder_in_content, Elementor\Frontend->get_builder_content, Elementor\Core\Base\Document->print_elements_with_wrapper, Elementor\Core\Base\Document->print_elements, Elementor\Element_Base->print_element, Elementor\Element_Base->print_content, Elementor\Element_Base->print_element, Elementor\Element_Base->print_content, Elementor\Element_Base->print_element, Elementor\Widget_Base->print_content, Elementor\Widget_Base->render_content, Elementor\Controls_Stack->render_by_mode, Puca_Elementor_Widget_Base->render, Puca_Elementor_Widget_Base->get_view_template, include('/themes/puca/elementor_templates/products.php'), wc_get_template, include('/themes/puca/woocommerce/layout-products/themes/fashion/carousel.php'), wc_get_template_part, load_template, require('/themes/puca-child/woocommerce/item-product/themes/fashion/inner.php'), do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, puca_child_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title, get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/puca-child/page-templates/woocommerce/archive-video.php'), WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.0.)

Answer (score 0):

The product_type property is deprecated in latest version of Woocomerce.Replace get_type() in all your themes\theme_name\woocommerce & functions.php

**So you need to replace this works for me:**

```
$product->product_type;
```

to this:

```
$product->get_type();
```